# How to correctly inference Redux Toolkit Slice generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, redux-toolkit

I am trying to write a function that takes a slice factory as argument, and does some computation on it.
I am having troubles setting up the types correctly.

Here is a minimal example to show the issue:

**Slice factory:**

```
export default function sliceFactory() {
    return createSlice({
        name: "addExercise",
        initialState: {
            query: "",
        },
        reducers: {
            startSearch(state) {
                state.query = "";
            },
            changeQuery(state, action) {
                state.query = action.payload;
            },
        },     
    });
}
```

The type of the `sliceFactory` function seems correctly inferred using:

```
type Test1 = typeof sliceFactory;
==> () => Slice<{
        query: string;
        }, {
            startSearch(state: WritableDraft<{query: string;}>): void;
            changeQuery(state: WritableDraft<{query: string;}>, 
                action: { payload: any; type: string;}): void;
        }, "addExercise">
```

**Utility function:**

```
function checkType<
    TState,
    TCaseReducers extends SliceCaseReducers<TState>,
    TName extends string,
    TSliceFactory extends () => Slice<TState, TCaseReducers, TName>,
>(sliceFactory: TSliceFactory) {
    return sliceFactory;
}
```

I expect to be able to inject `sliceFactory` inside, and get types inferred correctly

```
const result = checkType(sliceFactory); 
type Test2 = typeof result ==> ideally, the same as before
```

Instead, I got this

```
type Test2 ==> () => Slice<unknown, SliceCaseReducers<unknown>, string>
```

And the classic error:

```
Argument of type '() => Slice<{ query: string; }, { startSearch(state: WritableDraft<{ query: string; }>): void; changeQuery(state: WritableDraft<{ query: string; }>, action: { payload: any; type: string; }): void; }, "addExercise">' 
is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Slice<unknown, SliceCaseReducers<unknown>, string>'.
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Where's the `checkType` function used? I ask because it seems that all you're trying to do is check the compile time type.

Comment: Yeah the function in this scenario is not useful, but that's the minimum reproducible example to help debug the issue. I intentionally removed all the context to isolate it as much as possible

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYlqdm) meet your requirements?

Comment: Wow, let's say it helped in finding the solution, thank you! If you have a proper explanation of what were wrong, and why this is actually working, please let me know. Also references to some documentations are good, unfortunately I have difficulties in finding advanced typescript docs and references.

Comment: Excuse me, I accidentally copied an older playground link from link shortening service, what I meant to copy/paste was [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlMYlm). I'll write an answer explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [0xts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028056/0xts) for the input.
I ended up doing this:

```
function checkType<
  TStoreFactory extends () => Slice<
    any,
    any,
    any
  >
>(sliceFactory: TSliceFactory) {
  // [ ... ] do things with sliceFactory
  return sliceFactory; // caller will receive factory correctly typed
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to do all this extra infer, check my new comment.

Comment: Right, just updated the answer. Thank you!